# Line breaks in `props.children`

Tags: reactjs

How to get the output of `props.children`without losing the line breaks.

For example:

```
<Test>
 hello

 world
</Test>
```

will come in `props.children` as `"hello world"` i.e, without the linebreaks. Is there any way to get the line breaks for the children?

P.S: One way is to do :

```
<Test>
 {`hello

 world`}
</Test>
```

I'm looking for a solution without backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<pre />` tag:

```
<Test>
 <pre>
  hello

  world
 </pre>
</Test>
```